# Working with turtle graphics in python and calling an imported function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have a function that I am using called drawOctogon(side):

```
def drawOctagon(side):
    count = 0

    while count < 8:
        c.forward(side)
        c.right(45)
        count += 1
```

And I need to call it in a separate file here:

```
def drawShapes():
    c.penup()
    c.setpos(100.0, 100.0)
    c.pendown()

    random.seed()
    numOct = random.randint(5, 11)
    length = 50

    while numOct > 0:
        drawOctagon(length)
        c.penup()
        c.forward(10)
        c.pendown()
        numOct -= 1
```

What I need it to do is start drawing at (100, 100) and then move 10 units to the right and print another until the 'numOct' is 0, but instead, it goes to (100,. 100) and then returns to (0,0) to draw the octagon.

Comment: Draws as you've intended over here, without returning to 0,0.  How are you calling `drawShapes()`?

Comment: I'm just running the file and then typing 'drawShapes()'

Comment: Okay, so I solved it. I forgot to say I was importing 'drawOctagon()' from another file, but in that separate file, I already initialized a separate turtle so it was just moving two separate turtles.